# In Firebase, how do I prevent myself (developer) from being able to read customer data?

Tags: database, firebase, encryption, firebase-realtime-database

The app user will generate and store plain text data, which may be sensitive and private. It's critical that only that user have access to that data and that the developer cannot read what a user has written.

How can I achieve this in Firebase? I understand this can be done through some encryption technology. But I'm not sure where I should look.

Comment: The first person who should be able to read the data is the developer, assume the data is encrypted in firebase, the client app will probably have the decryption code which will make it readable to the developer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be (and has been) done. You''ll have to encrypt/decrypt both the values and the paths at which you store these values on the clients and then use an out-of-bounds way to distributing the encryption/decryption keys.

While searching I found this very simple implementation of an encrypted chat: https://github.com/Dissimilis/FirebaseChat

Comment: Excellent. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "out-of-bounds way to distributing the keys" and how one goes about this?